# How to use selenium Script code for each script?

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on automate a website pages and I have written nearly 15 scripts. Now the problem is each scripts first priority is login or every time site requires login so currently I have used login code in starting of each script.

Is there anyway to create a file or package for login to use it in each and every script so I can skip login code from each script?

Comment: Are you using testng as well ?

Comment: Yes, Need to test the website scenarios

Comment: okay, I have given the answer below, do check it out and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can write **login** in `@BeforeMethod` and **logout** in `@AfterMethod`

See

**@BeforeMethod**

> The annotated method will be run before each test method.

and

**@AfterMethod**

> The annotated method will be run after each test method.

so if you have login in `@BeforeMethod`, it'd get automatically triggered before each `@Test`, so you don't have to write login functionality again and again.

Comment: Thanks for the Help but can you please explain how to implement it .

Comment: My code looks like this public class XYZ 
{
 WebDriver driver;

 @Test(priority=1)
 public void Login () throws InterruptedException 
 {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("site URL");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();


 
  WebElement txtbx_Email=driver.findElement(By.name("Email"));
  txtbx_Email.sendKeys("mailID");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: change `@Test` to `@BeforeTest`

Comment: @DotsTester  : Did it resolve your query ?

Comment: i will replace test by Beforetest but then how to use in all scripts?

Comment: as mentioned before, @beforetest will execute automatically prior to any test in your code, so do that and let me know if that works